# Is there a good tutorial to use boost with openCV?

Tags: boost, opencv

I am very familiar with OpenCV and currently using version 2.3.1. i have so far been using STL containers for my regular use. I have heard that there is a progressive use and demand of Boost containers. How can i begin with it. I have never used BOOST earlier. can i get some good references?

Comment: What kind of use do you want to do?

Comment: i am working real time tracking of objects... i wish to explore the power of boost here. also i want  to learn to use graph library of boost and work with image processing. can i find directions there?

Answer (score 1):

Check this site http://www.boost.org/. It contains very good references, examples, tutorials, and all you need for a good start.

But keep in mind that, while using the power of boost, you will miss the simple and elegant integration of STL and OpenCV.

By example, you can now write

```
vector<float> vec;
...
Mat m(vec);
```

And you have the matrix. For boost, you will have to write your own conversion routines.